# Regarding Comparing JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

There was a question raised by Log1x about Comparing JSON after foreach loop for a Discord Channel Viewer

This is the link: [Comparing JSON after foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930207/comparing-json-after-foreach-loop) In his viewer he wanted to output something like:

```
<ul>
  <li>Channel 1
    <ul>
      <li>User 1</li>
      <li>User 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Channel 2</li>
  <li>Channel 3
    <ul>
      <li>User 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

There was an excellent answer on how to do this, from Mojtaba which was:

```
$discord = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/servers/'.$id.'/widget.json'));
  if ($discord->channels) {
    usort($discord->channels, function($a, $b) {
      return $a->position > $b->position ? 1 : -1;
    });

    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ($discord->members as $member) {
        if (!empty($member->channel_id)) {
            $channel_members[$member->channel_id][] = $member->username;
        }
    }

    foreach ($discord->channels as $channel) {
      echo "<li>{$channel->name}";
      if (!empty($channel_members[$channel->id])) {
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($channel_members[$channel->id] as $username) {
              echo "<li>$username</li>";
            }
            echo '</ul>';
      }
      echo "</li>";
    }

    echo '</ul>';
  }
```

I have already completed my viewer but you will be able to see from this screen-shot [link](http://raw-recruits.com/images/screenshot.png) that my available space is limited and taken up by too many empty channels. So I am interested to know if there is a way to hide channels that are empty i.e.

```
<ul>
  <li>Channel 1
    <ul>
      <li>User 1</li>
      <li>User 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Channel 3
    <ul>
      <li>User 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As I have said, my interest is also for a Discord Channel Viewer , so the above information from both Mojtaba and the first link are directly relevant to my code too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to just move your `<li>` tag inside the `if`.

```
foreach ($discord->channels as $channel) {

    // outside the if, the channel shows even if it's empty

    if (!empty($channel_members[$channel->id])) {

        // inside the if, you'll only see the channel if it's not empty 

        echo "<li>{$channel->name}<ul>";
        foreach ($channel_members[$channel->id] as $username) {
            echo "<li>$username</li>";
        }
        echo '</ul></li>';
    }
}
```